# Left derivation and right derivation for the following grammar

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction

This is such a simple topic, I'm embarrassed for myself. But I'm doing some review problems before the semester starts, and I've realized that I'm totally blanking on this topic.

Assuming the grammar:

```
int = int digit | digit
digit = 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19
```

Write out a left derivation and a right derivation for:

```
15 14 13 12
```

I know it should look something like:

```
int => int digit
=> int digit digit
=> int digit digit digit
=> digit digit digit digit
```

...but then I'm not sure what to do (or even if that much is right), nor do I get how to do it in the other direction!

So it would be wonderful if someone could explain to me a) how to do this in the future, and b) give the answer so I can check that I understand the process.
I really appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leftmost and rightmost derivation are the same in this case, which is as you showed.

The leftmost derivation expands the leftmost nonterminal first; the rightmost derivation expands the rightmost nonterminal first.

[Wikipedia has good examples.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees)  For the grammar

```
S → S + S
S → 1
S → a
```

This is a leftmost derivation:

```
S → S + S
  → 1 + S
  → 1 + S + S
  → 1 + 1 + S
  → 1 + 1 + a
```

This is a rightmost derivation:

```
S → S + S
  → S + a
  → S + S + a
  → S + 1 + a
  → 1 + 1 + a
```

Comment: Okay...I kind of get that, but how do I take into account that I'm not starting with 10 or 19, but with 12 or 15 depending on the direction?

Comment: @user2309856: They're all `digit`s, there's no difference between any of them... I'm not sure what you mean, could you clarify?

Comment: so would it be int=>int digit=>int 15=>int digit 15=>int 14 15=>int digit 14 15=>int 13 14 15=>digit 13 14 15=>12 13 14 15?

Comment: @user2309856: Oh, you're treating `digit` as a nonterminal, I didn't realize that. No it would be `int=>int digit=>int 12=>int digit 12=>int 13 12=>int digit 13 12=>int 14 13 12=>digit 14 13 12=>15 14 13 12`...